# Trying to understand error length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent in R data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is my original function:

```
best <- function(state=NULL, outcome){
    colNum <- list("heart attack" = 11, "heart failure" = 17, "pneumonia" = 23)[outcome]
    if (!is.null(colNum[[1]])){
        df <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")[,c(2,7,colNum[[1]])]
        df <- df[df[2] == state & df[3] != "Not Available",]
        if(nrow(df)==0){stop("invalid state")}
        df
    } else {stop("invalid outcome")}
}
```

When I call `best(outcome = "heart attack")` I get the following error:

```
 Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 
 length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Debug shows the error being thrown on this line:

```
df <- df[df[2] == state & df[3] != "Not Available",]
```

However, when I change this line to `df <- df[df[[2]] == state & df[[3]] != "Not Available",]` the code runs correctly.

Alternatively, if I change the default value of `state` to "NULL" instead of `NULL`, I also don't get an error.

I believe the problem is something to do with the fact the `length(NULL) == 0` but what I don't quite understand is why this problem is negated by including the double square brackets here `df <- df[df[[2]] == state & df[[3]] != "Not Available",]`. I also was under the assumption that it was good practise to use `NULL` as a default argument value but this suggests not?

The following function I wrote purely to recreate the error without the CSV so feel free to use:

```
best2 <- function(state=NULL, outcome=NULL){
    df <- data.frame(hospital = c("H1", "H2", "H3"), state = c("NY","NY","CA"), mortality = c("Not Available", "14.1", "16.2"))
    df <- df[df[2] == state & df[3] != "Not Available",]
    df
}
```

If you call `best2()` with single square brackets it throws the same `Error in matrix` but with double square brackets it throws a warning `Warning message: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'` but runs.

So my questions are:

1) Please can someone explain how the error is occurring?
2) Is it bad practise to use 'NULL' as default value?
3) What is the difference between `df[2]` and `df[[2]]` here? Using the `class()` function `df[2]` is a data.frame and `df[[2]]` is a character vector but I'm confused about why they both work, why one affects the aforementioned error and which is best practise to use.

Comment: What is your function's intended output? Any sample data to test it with?

Comment: for your third question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el

Comment: @NelsonGon please use the best2 function. This recreates the problem with out the csv

Comment: Always have data as input, never inside the function. Easier to manipulate that way. You need `[,2]` or `[[2]]` ie `df <- df[df[,2] == state & df[,3] != "Not Available",]`

Comment: @NelsonGon is there a way to upload csv to stack? why does df[2] work when state != NULL?

Comment: You can use `dput(head(df,n))` to share data. The reason your `best2` errors is due to subsetting. See jogo's attached question for more. [How to upload data to Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Comparing `iris[1]` with `iris[[1]]` should be elucidating. The former returns a subset of the data.frame, which is still a data.frame. The latter extracts the column vector from the data.frame.